# Use variables inside an anonymous function, which is defined somewhere else

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

When using anonymous functions in PHP, you can easily use variables from right outside of its scope by using the `use()` keyword.

In my case the anonymous functions are already defined somewhere, but called later on (somewhere else) in a class.

The following piece of code is to illustrate the idea:

```
<?php

$bla = function ( $var1 ) use ($arg)
        {
            echo $var1;
        };

class MyClass
{
    private $func;

    public function __construct ( $func )
    {
        $this->func = $func;
    }

    public function test ( $arg )
    {
        $closure =  $this->func;
        $closure ( 'anon func' );
    }
}

$c = new MyClass($bla);
$c->test ( 'anon func' );
```

What i'm doing is i create an `anonymous function` and store that in a variable. I pass that variable to the method of a class and that is where i want to run the *anonymous* function.

But i can't use the `use()` keyword to get the `$arg` parameter from the `method` this way. Because the *anonymous* function was declared outside of the `method`.

But i really need a way to get the variables from the method where the anonymous function is run from. Is there a way to do that, when the anonymous function is declared somewhere else..?

Comment: Pass it as a parameter instead.

Comment: @NiclasLarsson I can't just do that. Because i need a way to alter the parameters by `reference` inside the `anonymous function`. I can easily get the values with `func_get_args` from inside the `test()` method. Then in there pass those values to the `anonymous function`, but that way it only gets a `copy` of the values. I need to have a `reference` to it.

Comment: Can't you pass them by reference by using the refrence operator (&)?

Comment: @NiclasLarsson by reference would not make it change scope though. In the OP's example, $arg would still point to the $arg from the global scope. I understood the OP wants the closure to use the $arg from the scope where it was executed, e.g. the MyClass::test($arg). But maybe the OP can clarify.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The point of the `use` keyword is to [inherit/close over a particular environment state from the parent scope](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) into the Closure *when it's defined*, e.g.

```
$foo = 1;

$fn = function() use ($foo) {
    return $foo;
};

$foo = 2;

echo $fn(); // gives 1
```

If you want `$foo` to be closed over at a later point, either define the closure later or, if you want `$foo` to be always the current value (2), pass `$foo` as a regular parameter.

Comment: Was hoping there was something i overlooked. But appearently there is no other way then to pass the needed variables as parameter.

Comment: you should mention it's called "Lexical Scoping". All modern programming languages use lexical scoping.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, you can do it if you use a `use reference` ([php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-160) ex 3.3) and a global, ugly since it uses globals, but just to put it out there:

```
<?php
$bla = function ( $var1 ) use (&$arg)
        {
            return "var1:$var1, arg:$arg";
        };

class MyClass
{
    private $func;

    public function __construct ( $func )
    {
        $this->func = $func;
    }

    public function test ( $param )
    {
        global $arg;
        $arg=$param;
        $closure =  $this->func;
        return  $closure ( 'anon func' );
    }
}

$c = new MyClass($bla);
echo $c->test ( 'bla bla' ); //var1:anon func, arg:bla bla
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @chiliNUT answer, rather than making $arg global, pass it by reference to the MyClass constructor:

```
class MyClass
{
    private
        $func,
        $arg;

    public function __construct ( $func , &$arg )
    {
        $this->func = $func;
        $this->arg = &$arg;
    }

    public function test ( $v )
    {
        $this->arg = $v;
        $closure =  $this->func;
        $closure ( 'anon func' );
    }
}

class RunIt
{
    public function run()
    {
        $arg = null;
        $bla = function($var1) use (&$arg)
        {
            echo $var1 . ' : ' . $arg;
        };
        $c = new MyClass($bla, $arg);
        $c->test ( 'this is arg' );
    }
}

(new RunIt())->run();
```

If you want to allow any number of use parameters:

```
class MyClass
{
    private
        $func,
        $args;

    public function __construct ( $func , &...$args )
    {
        $this->func = $func;
        $this->args = &$args;
    }

    public function test ( ...$vs )
    {
        foreach($vs as $i => $v) if($i < count($this->args)) $this->args[$i] = $v;
        $closure =  $this->func;
        $closure ( 'anon func' );
    }
}

class RunIt
{
    public function run()
    {
        $arg1 = '';
        $arg2 = '';
        $arg3 = '';
        $bla = function($var1) use (&$arg1, &$arg2, &$arg3)
        {
            echo $var1 . ' : ' . $arg1 . ' : ' . $arg2 . ' : ' . $arg3;
        };
        $c = new MyClass($bla, $arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
        $c->test ( 'this is arg1', 'this is arg2' ); //$arg3 retains its previous value
    }
}

(new RunIt())->run();
```