# PHP Redefine a closure with bind() and its scope

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use variables inside an anonymous function, which is defined somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138908/use-variables-inside-an-anonymous-function-which-is-defined-somewhere-else)

In PHP >= 5.4 we have a `Closure` class with the `bind` or `bindTo` methods to *bind* an anonymous function to an object, so that the closure has access to the `$this` variable, as if it was defined inside that class.

A simple example:

```
<?php
$closure = function() {
    echo $this->bla; //prints "bbb"
};

class A
{
    public $bla = 'bbb';
    public function blaat($closure)
    {
        $someVar = 'something';

        $bc = Closure::bind($closure, $this, 'A');
        $bc();
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->blaat($closure);
```

That is all very nice and all, but what about the `use` keyword..?

When i *rebind* a closure inside the method of a class, then i probably want the `closure` to have access to the "locally" defined variables aswell, so its parent scope. For example the `$someVar` variable in the above example. But the `bind` method of the `Closure` class doesn't care about the `use` keywords or the abillity to use variables from the parent scope.

It feels somewhat incomplete this way... Anyone any idea if this ever gets supported, or perhaps if there is already a way to use the parent scoped variables when redefining a `closure` with the `bind` or `bindTo` method?

Comment: As I understand, passing variables in parent scope as arguments to closure is not what you're looking for?

Comment: @barius No that is indeed not what i'm looking for. Because my closures are added dynamically to certain methods. See it as a *plugin* system. So the writer of the plugin (the closure) knows what `variables` he needs from the `method`. But the method self doesn't know what `variables` to pass to the `closure`. It only knows that it should invoke the `closure`.

Comment: I don't think this is a good way to extend things. This makes `closure` fully dependent on the `method`. Changing the name of local variable should definately not break any of the plug-ins, and this is not the case in this scenario.

Comment: @barius That's a perfectly good point, but as i see it plugins tend to break anyway, one way or the other. For example, when code is changed. I see this all the time with Wordpress, jQuery or even FireFox, where `plugins` need an update because the `framework` just got a major update. I don't think it will be any different in my case. Guess it's just a matter of choice.

Comment: Extensibility should be provided by interfaces - plugins implement interface of some khind. While the interface does not change, the plug-in works as it worked. Interface can be, of course, `interface` in PHP, naming and parameters of public functions etc. But it should be as small as possible - that's why we have public and private functions in PHP5, not only public ones.