# Build query using laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.5, laravel-query-builder

You will find the entire function at bottom. I want the query to be like this, but in laravel query builder:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE (sender='$receiver' AND 
           receiver='$sender'AND status='sent') OR (sender='$sender' AND 
           receiver='$receiver'AND status='sent')";
```

This query is supposed to retrieve message from chat where for eg: sender=3 and receiver=4 and vice versa. Basically chat between those two individuals.

Now I made something like this in laravel which returns the entire chat table where it should only retrieve chats between the given sender and receiver. I know the problem is something in where and orWhere clause.

```
     public function reloadChat(Request $request)
{
    $sender = $request["sender"] ;
    $receiver = $request["receiverid"] ;

    $chats =  DB::table('chats')
                    -> where(['sender_id' => $sender , 'receiver_id' => $receiver , 'status' => "sent" ])
                    -> orWhere(['sender_id' => $receiver , 'receiver_id' => $sender , 'status' => "sent" ])

                    ->get();



                    foreach ($chats as $result)
                    {
                        if($result->sender_id==$sender)
                        {
                            echo "<div class=msgsend>".$result->message."</div>";
                        }else{
                            echo "<div class=msgrec>".$result->message."</div>";
                        }

                    }

}
```

P.S. - ABsolutely new to laravel

edit:
[image: this happens only when i pass the sender and receiver id's actual value in numbers(hard code) in where clause]

this works. but when i use variables instead of 3 and 4 id, then it doesnt.

```
    public function reloadChat(Request $request)
    {
    $sender = $request["sender"] ;
    $receiver = $request["receiverid"] ;
    var_dump($sender) ;
    var_dump($receiver) ;
    $chats =  DB::table('chats')
                    -> where(function($query) {
                         $query->where('sender_id', "3")
                               ->where('receiver_id', "4")
                               ->where('status', "sent");
                        })
                    -> orWhere(function($query) {
                         $query->where('sender_id', "4")
                                ->where('receiver_id', "3")
                                ->where('status', "sent");
                        })->get();

    }
```

Comment: Did one of the posted answer helped you? If so, you can mark one as accepted.

Comment: @KakashiHatake try adding variable closure for example `$chats =  DB::table('chats')->where(function($query) use($sender, $receiver,)
{
    $query->where(['sender_id' => $sender , 'receiver_id' => "1", 'status' => "sent" ]);
})` I didn't test it but it will work. You can look at this resource for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138908/use-variables-inside-an-anonymous-function-which-is-defined-somewhere-else

Comment: @Qh0stM4N yes I made it work a week ago. Both the answers were right query-wise. But then I figured out that I was supposed to use the "use" keyword for accessing my variables inside the anonymous function for query. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit documentations [Advanced wheres](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres)

Example use

```
$chats =  DB::table('chats')->where(function($query)
{
    $query->where(['sender_id' => $sender , 'receiver_id' => "1", 'status' => "sent" ]);
})->orWhere(function($query)
{
    $query->where(['sender_id' => "2", 'receiver_id' => "1", 'status' => "sent" ])
})->toSql();
```

toSql(); = return created sql command without parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 $chats = \DB::table('chats')
    -> where(function($query) {
        $query->where('sender_id', $sender)
            ->where('receiver_id', $receiver)
            ->where('status', status)
    })
    -> orWhere(function($query) {
        $query->where('sender_id', $receiver)
            ->where('receiver_id', $sender)
            ->where('status', status)
    })->get();
```

The code I posted simulates the parenthesis, so it's the same behavior as your original query. If it does not work, I think the problem is elsewhere and you may have to re-check with your original query, or your parameters.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. i tried your code and the query works but only when i hardcode the sender and receiver id's. when i use the variables $sender an $receiver the query doesn't work.I have done the vardump of the variables as seen in the chatbox pic where it shows 3 and 4 in string type. Your query is right but it is not recognising the variable's value.But it works when i hardcode the id's.